# flask sub function not yielding results

Tags: python, flask

I have a bunch of code (1300 lines) that is working correctly and I am trying to incorporate flask into the picture.  In order to do this, I an trying to use flask.Response to call a function within my method, that calls another method in my class.

Here is test code that re-creates my problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import flask

class TestClass(object):

    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def worker(self):
        yield 'print test\n'

    @app.route('/')
    def test_method_get_stuff():
        return flask.render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
    def test_method_post_stuff():
        def test_method_sub_function():
            tc.worker()
        return flask.Response(test_method_sub_function(),mimetype= 'text/plain')


tc = TestClass()
tc.app.run(debug=True)
```

`index.html` just has a text box with a submit button.

The issue I have is once you click the submit button, the request goes through sucessfully but the page is blank with no errors in the python command line or in the browser, and what I expect to happen is to show in plain text "print test" with a newline.'

Any assistance would be appreciated.  I am trying to avoid completely re-writing all my code.  With the understanding that i will have to replace 'print' with 'yield' commands in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your nested `test_method_sub_function()` function doesn't return anything; it simply creates the generator (by calling a generator function), then exits.

It should at the very least *return* the `tc.worker()` call:

```
def test_method_sub_function():
    return tc.worker()
```

at which point the route works. You may as well skip this nested function however and use `tc.worker()` *directly*:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def test_method_post_stuff():
    return flask.Response(tc.worker(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

One note: although your use of the `Flask` object as a class attribute happens to work, you should to put it in a class. Leave the `app` object and routes outside of the class:

```
import flask

class TestClass(object):    
    def worker(self):
        yield 'print test\n'

tc = TestClass()
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test_method_get_stuff():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def test_method_post_stuff():
    return flask.Response(tc.worker(), mimetype='text/plain')

app.run(debug=True)
```