# return multiple generators python

Tags: python, flask, generator

This is in reference to [flask sub function not yielding results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345290/flask-sub-function-not-yielding-results)

How can I return multiple generators, like so ...

Currently no matter what I try, it does the first one only, for instance if I do a list of generators and loop through that, it still does the first one.

Any thoughts?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import flask
import time

class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def worker(self):
        a='1234'
        b=a + '45\n'
        yield b
        time.sleep(3)
        yield a

    def worker2(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        c = '9876'
        yield c

tc = TestClass()
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def test_method_get_stuff():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def test_method_post_stuff():
    def test_method_sub_function():
        return tc.worker()
        return tc.worker2()
    return flask.Response(test_method_sub_function(),mimetype= 'text/plain')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `return` you *exit the function*; anything after that line won't be executed.

Instead, you'll have to *chain* your generators. Use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) here:

```
from itertools import chain

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def test_method_post_stuff():
    def test_method_sub_function():
        return chain(tc.worker(), tc.worker2())
    return flask.Response(test_method_sub_function(),mimetype= 'text/plain')
```

Comment: exactly what i needed.   i can now incorporate my previous code.  thanks!

Comment: @user1601716: so is the previous answer still helpful to you then? You unaccepted that after accepting it. :-)